# Get next two months using {{currentDate | date:'MMM'}}

Tags: html

Using `{{currentDate | date:'MMM'}}` we get the current month. But how do we get the next two months using this logic?

I tried using 'MMM+1' and '+1 MMM' but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use pipe like this for date:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'addMonth'
})
export class AddMonthPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: Date | number): number {
    const date = new Date(value);
    return date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
  }

}
```

And in HTML:

```
 {{currentDate | addMonth | date:'MMM'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in HTML : -

CURRENT MONTH: `{{currentDate | date:'MMM'}} <br>`

NEXT MONTH:    `{{addMonthInCurrentDateValue(1) | date:'MMM'}} <br>`

NEXT TO NEXT MONTH: `{{addMonthInCurrentDateValue(2) | date:'MMM'}} <br>`

Add following code in .ts file.

```
addMonthInCurrentDateValue(n) {


let endDate: Date;
let today = new Date();
const nmonth = today.getMonth() + n;
var nextMonthDate = new Date(today.setMonth(today.getMonth() + n));
endDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), nmonth, 0);
return today;


}
```